# I am trying to create multi line variable in bash but facing error "unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)' "

Tags: linux, bash

I tried to write function in bash. Input to the function is ip address of host. Function should ssh to host and run multiple command on remote host.

I defined multi-line variable but getting following error.

./RCAatuo.sh: line 8: unexpected EOF while looking for matching `)'
./RCAatuo.sh: line 14: syntax error: unexpected end of file

```sh
loginvCUvDU()
{
 echo hellow
 HostIpv6=$1
 echo $HostIpv6
 su_cmd= "$(cat <<-EOF
 echo ----------hi----
 EOF
 )"
sshpass -p $vDUvCUPass ssh -tt vm-root@$HostIpv6 "$su_cmd"
}
```

Comment: It would help if you formatted your code properly.  Reading you post, it comes through as one long line.

Comment: `<<-EOF` only allows the closing `EOF` to be indented with tabs, not spaces.

Comment: Also, you can't have a space between `var=` and the value on the right-hand side of an assignment. That is, `var=$(buildAValue)` and `var= $(buildAValue)` are two *completely* different commands, and only the first one changes `var` outside the scope of the single line.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On surface there is no need to embed the `<<` into the command substitution ( "$cat <<"). From the question, looks like the goal is to pass multiple command to sshpass

```
loginvCUvDU()
{
 echo hellow
 HostIpv6=$1
 echo $HostIpv6
 # Multiline constant
 su_cmd="
 echo ----------hi----
 echo ----------CMD2----
 "
sshpass -p $vDUvCUPass ssh -tt vm-root@$HostIpv6 "$su_cmd"
}
```

As a side note the issue is the using the '-EOF' separator. The logic for striping tabs does not apply in this case, as the string is to be remotely executed. As a result, bash does not see the EOF indicator (prefixed with space). EDIT: Per comments, possible that this is not an issue. Hard to tell if the gap before terminate 'EOF' is tab or space.

The following will change will allow the code to pass parsing (1) eliminate space after su_cmd=, and (2) remove the space before the EOF.

```
su_cmd="$(cat <<EOF
 echo ----------hi----
EOF
)"
```

Comment: I'm not clear what you mean here. `<<-EOF` has no logic for stripping space at alls; it only strips leading *tabs*.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for pointing the tab/space behavior. Hard to tell from the question, if code was using tab or space for indentation.